# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1171- 1176: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, twitter, encoding

I am trying to export all my twitter subscriptions as OPML, but keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "twopy.py", line 103, in <module>
    template.render(feeds = feeds)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1171-
1176: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/melekes/ab883732050e577cd7890b4953847529

I've already tried setting env vars `LC_ALL/LANG` and adding `encode('utf-8')` to `feeds` like:

```
'name': u['name'].encode('utf-8'),
'feed_url': urljoin(r.url, m.attrib.get('href')).encode('utf-8'),
'html_url': r.url.encode('utf-8')
```

Also, I've tried adding `.encode('utf-8')` to `TEMPLATE`. Any other ideas? There are questions like this, but I am just stuck with this, sorry.

And thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`unicode(your_str, 'utf-8', errors="ignore")`.